# How can we insert into multiple tables in oracle using dapper in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I have 3 Tables.
Table_main (primary key-pk_main)
Table A- (PRimary key - PK_A) and pk is the foreign key.
Tab B- (Primary key - PK_B) and PK_A is the foreign key.

Can we do this using Dapper?
Also with a single query?

If not can it be done by opening the DB connection just once, and not multiple times for different table insertions.

Comment: Dapper does not support insertion. You need Dapper-Contrib or another layer on top of Dapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert in multiple tables using a single query. But, you can insert in a single connection.

```
public IDbconnection OpenDbConnection()
{
    var dbconnection = new OracleConnection();
    if(dbconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        dbconnection.Open();
    }
}
public void BeginTrans()
{
    _db = OpenDbConnection(ConnectionStringHere);
    _tran = _db.BeginTransaction();
}

public void CommitTrans()
{
    _tran.Commit();
    if(_db.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        _db.Close(); // close db connection
}
public void RollbackTrans()
{
    _tran.Rollback();
    if(_db.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        _db.Close(); // close db connection
}
```

You can write these methods in the same class with an interface (ex IDbInterface, DbClass). You can have two properties injected in the constructor  _db and _tran.

You can use these methods as

```
try
{
   // BeginTrans method 
   Your logic and queries
   // CommitTrans
}
catch
{
   //RollbackTrans
}
```